# SIGSEGV error in C++ code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Could anyone explain why this code gives an SIGSEGV error.

It gives the error on CodeChef for the problem http://www.codechef.com/TCFS15P/problems/SPIDY2

I have tried checking for any out of bound array calls but cant seem to figure out any.

```
 using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;

ll ab(ll x)
{
    return (x>0)?x:-x;
}

vector<ll> height;



ll dps(ll n,ll score, ll index)
{



if (index == n)
{
    return score;
}


ll mins = INT_MAX;
ll k=0;
ll temp = 0;
ll add = 0;

for(k=1;(index+k) <= n ; k = (2*k) )
{

    if ((index+k)>n)
    {
        break;
    }

    add = ab(height[index+k]-height[index]);

    temp = dps(n , score + add , index+k );
    if (temp < mins)
    {
        mins = temp;
    }
}



return mins;

}

int main()
{
ll n,i,temp;
cin>>n;

height.push_back(0);

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    cin>>temp;

    height.push_back(temp);
}

ll value = 0;
value = dps(n,0,1);
cout<<value<<endl;

height.clear();

return 0;
```

Comment: Note: array, STL container index starts from 0. You need to make sure your index is not out-of-boundry

Comment: It runs ok for me: http://ideone.com/Qzspe2